# Meteor - Google Maps marker click event

Tags: google-maps, meteor

I want when the user clicks on a marker, I would like a popup displays to him with some information (for example: lets say the markers represent locations, when he clicks on a marker it displays to him all information of this location)

What is the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Pretty sure Google Maps generates custom events for things like that. If yo are using React, there is a [npm package I used for GM](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) that worked well, and I think one of their examples was how to implement custom click events on the markers.

Comment: I am using just meteor (Blaze in frontend)..

Comment: Do not just use GMAPs right out of the box - use the package mentioned in my answer or you will spend time reinventing the wheel. This package will handle any load order operations.

Comment: No it's okay ! Thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

See the [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple) documentation for how to setup event listeners on your markers.  You should be able to do that in your Blaze template code, most likely in the `onCreated()` or `onRendered()` of the template.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    swal({
         title: "More details",
         text: "Type what you want here", 
       });
});
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Add this package https://github.com/dburles/meteor-google-maps

**HTML**

```
{{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
```

**Client JS**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    GoogleMaps.load({
        v: '3',
        key: 'YOUR_KEY'
    });
});

Template.YOUR_TEMPLATE.helpers({
    mapOptions: () => {
        if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
            return {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_MAP_LAT, YOUR_MAP_LNG),
                zoom: 1
            };
        }
    }
});

Template.YOUR_TEMPLATE.onRendered(function(){
    GoogleMaps.ready('map', function(map) {
        let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(YOUR_MARKER_LAT, YOUR_MARKER_LNG),
           map: map.instance
        })
       let infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
           content: 'SOME CONTENT'
       })
       marker.addListener('click', function(event){
             infowindow.open(map.instance, marker);
       })


    });
});
```